# Sign in with Apple using Vapor 4

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift

I'm trying to implement Sign In with Apple using Vapor 4
I followed Vapor Docs
But when I use the api and send user's token (even as a request header or in the body), it returns the following error

```
{
    "error": true,
    "reason": "Data corrupted at path ''. The given data was not valid JSON. Underlying error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 \"Invalid value around line 1, column 0.\" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}."
}
```

As I mentioned, I used two different method.
First one, sending user token in the body:

```
    func SignInWithApple(req: Request)async throws -> Token{
        //Decode request body -> succeeded
        let data = try req.content.decode(SignInWithAppleToken.self)
        //The bundle id of the iOS app
        guard let appIdentifier = Environment.get("ios_app_id") else{
            throw Abort(.internalServerError)
        }
        //The error happens at this line
        let siwaToken = try await req.jwt.apple.verify(data.token, applicationIdentifier: appIdentifier)
        print(siwaToken)

//Rest of logic
}
```

Second one, sending user token in request header (Bearer)

```
func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
 app.jwt.apple.applicationIdentifier = "iOS_app_bundle_Id"
    app.get("apple") { req async throws -> HTTPStatus in
        let token = try await req.jwt.apple.verify()
        print(token) // AppleIdentityToken
        return .ok
    }
}
```

This how I send the request in postman:
1- Sending data in request body (for method 1):
[image: 1- Sending data in request body (for method 1):]

2- Sending data in request header (for method ):
[image: 2- Sending data in request header (for method ):]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check to see if your server automatically adds data to the request. For me, a PHP file on my server was including text (for a page that needed json) that corrupt the json, and needed to be modified. If you use infinityfree and get this error, then I'm also not sure how to fix it without paying them (I didn't pay them)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code that generates the API call that, in turn, generates the error?  Your question will attract close votes as it is too vague to generate substantive answers.

Comment: I am not familiar with Apple authentication/authorization, but tokens are not JSON. Internally they are often JSON, but the JSON in encoded into something else such as JWT. Where is that error occurring?

Comment: As mentioned above this isn't a problem with the Vapor code - the request body that you're sending it is not valid JSON. How are you sending it?

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely because you're sending the `identityToken` as is which is `Data`, but you need to convert it to `String` before sending it to your backend with something like this:

```
func handleAppleSignIn(_ auth: ASAuthorization) {
    guard let credential = auth.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential else {
        print("Invalid Apple ID credential")
        return
    }

    guard let idToken = credential.identityToken, let idTokenString = String(data: idToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
        print("Unable to convert identityToken to String")
        return
    }

    print(idTokenString)
    // rest of the logic
}
```